# Conditional If statement within table visual basic database (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, t-sql

I would like to create a column that displays if a student has passed or failed. To pass the overall grade needs to be above 40.

I have done this before using access using the following:

```
IIf([Overall]<=40,"fail","pass")
```

But I’m very new to visual basic. Anyone got any ideas on how I can do this?

The IDE I am using is Visual Studio

This is the table

[image]

Or if there are any tutorials that you would recommend that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in your table definition:

- You can use a `CASE WHEN` statement to check for a criteria and provide a value.
- You can not refer to a computed column in another computed column.

So you can add a column like this:

```
[ColumnName] AS CASE WHEN (the formula for overall) <= 40 THEN 'fail' ELSE 'pass' END
```

Also you can make the result as a `bit` (boolean) data type and let the application decide to show a string instead of true or false.

Comment: ahhh right I see thank you my good man, and also thank you Reza for the idea of making the result a bit data type, then I can refer to the true or false result differently throughout my forms if needed instead of using just pass or fail.